# Why are both parent and child pid showing

Tags: c, fork

Ive created this program that loops 5 times creating a child process with fork() and have the PID put into a int array and prints each array element out as it loops but why does it show the parent and child PID.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    int i, nPIDStore[12];
    for (i = 0; i <5; i++) {
        fork();
        nPIDStore[i] = getpid();
        printf("%d\n", nPIDStore[i]);
        getchar();
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Because both parent and child are printing out their PIDs, as you instructed them to. You're going to end up creating upwards of 30 processes, with this code.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: There will be exactly `factorial(5) == 120` processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors, here:

1. All your children also `fork()`, which means you're going to be creating 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120 processes, which is probably not what you want. When `fork()` returns 0, you're in the child, so unless you want this behavior, you have to have the child do something else.
2. You're storing the PID of the parent, in `nPIDStore`, not the PID of the child. You need to store the result from `fork()` in that array, there's no easy way to get the PIDs of your children if you don't store that result.
3. You're not `wait()`ing for your children to die. In this case, they will get reaped by `init` anyway, but it's better form to wait for them yourself.
4. You don't check the returns from any of your system calls, including `fork()`.
5. `main()` returns `int`.

This is probably closer to what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nPIDStore[12];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        pid_t p = fork();
        if ( p == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling fork()");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else if ( p == 0 ) {

            /*  In the child  */

            printf("Child %zu created with pid %d.\n", i + 1, (int) getpid());
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;    /*  Stop the child from doing anything else  */
        }
        else {

            /*  In the parent  */

            nPIDStore[i] = p;
            printf("Pid of child %zu is %d\n", i + 1, nPIDStore[i]);
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i ) {
        if ( waitpid(nPIDStore[i], NULL, 0) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling waitpid()");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else {
            printf("Child %zu reaped.\n", i + 1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and outputs:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./fork
Pid of child 1 is 9536
Pid of child 2 is 9537
Child 1 created with pid 9536.
Pid of child 3 is 9538
Child 2 created with pid 9537.
Pid of child 4 is 9539
Pid of child 5 is 9540
Child 3 created with pid 9538.
Child 1 reaped.
Child 2 reaped.
Child 3 reaped.
Child 4 created with pid 9539.
Child 5 created with pid 9540.
Child 4 reaped.
Child 5 reaped.
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply do you have any idea why my array I put into the child process section isn't changing each element to 1 to represent the child being alive. Here is the section of code. `for (i = 0; i < nr_children; ++i) {
        children[i] = fork();
        if (children[i] == 0) {
            printf("In Child %d\n", getpid());
  childrenAlive[i]=1; 
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
           printf("In Parent %d\n", children[i]);
   
          getchar();
       }
    }`

Comment: @user3805878: This should be asked in a new question, not in a comment, but the answer is it is changing your array. It's just changing it in the child process which `exit()`s immediately afterwards, so there is no visible effect of it being changed. Different processes have different memory spaces, they'll each have their own copy of that array, and changing it in the child process will not affect the array in the parent process.

Comment: So even though the declaration is global the change is only in the process.

Comment: @user3805878: Well, it's not global in the code you provided, but even if it was, it makes no difference, no. Once you've `fork()`ed, then that's it, the new process is off by itself and the original parent process will never seen any changes, whether variables are global or otherwise. You have to use actual inter-process communication facilities to have the processes communicate with each other, which are not trivial.

Comment: So would this code create a structure only in that child `if (children[i] == 0) {
            printf("In Child %d\n", getpid());
            struct printJob job;
            job.jobID = getpid();
            job.jobPriority = getPriority();
            printf("Job ID : %d\nJob Priority : %d\n", job.jobID, job.jobPriority);
            exit(0);` But how does one receive information from that child.

Comment: Again, this stuff belongs in new questions, not comments. To get information from a child beyond an exit status, you have to use IPC facilities, such as pipes, shared memory, message queues, files, signals, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not differentiating between the parent and the cild while doing `getpid()` and printing it..

You know `fork()` returns `0` to the child process and the `pid` of the child to the parent process, so

```
flag = fork();
if(flag == 0)
{
    //this will be executed in the child process
    nPIDStore[i] = getpid();
    printf("%d\n", nPIDStore[i]);
}
```

But, again as you are doing this in a loop. the child of the last iteration will also become the parent of the next iteration.. and that would lead to the creation of `(2^5)-1` child processed.. so keep that in mind..

Answer (score 0):

That is the way fork works. Fork creates a complete copy of the process image including the process introduction code and the current instruction pointer. After fork returns you have two nearly identical processes that are at the statement after the fork call. One (the child) received 0 as return value from fork the other (the parent) received the process ID of the newly created process.

Perhaps you wanted something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const size_t nr_children = 5;

int main() {
    pid_t children[nr_children];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nr_children; ++i) {
        children[i] = fork();
        if (children[i] == 0) {
            printf("In Child %d\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            printf("In Parent %d\n", children[i]);
            getchar();
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nr_children; ++i)
        waitpid(children[i], NULL, 0);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the `pid_t children[nr_children]` do does it create an array of 5 process's.